# Storing words for ios offline flashcard app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to build a flashcard app that requires words and definitions to be stored somewhere on the device. What is the correct/best way to store this information? I have read about ways to prepopulate Core Data but the solutions I've read seem like hacks. This seems like a basic feature needed by many apps so am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data is the way to go here. There is nothing hacky about pre-populating a persistent store and including it in your app bundle.

Comment: After reading up on plists I think Core Data is the way to go. There is quite a bit of data I need to store, definitely more than the maximum of 2MB recommended for plists.

Answer (score 0):

Core Data seems like overkill for a flashcard app. I'd probably just save the contents to a plist. Is this content read-only, or do you need to update it at runtime?

If you need to updated it you could copy check for a plist in the documents directory at launch, and if it doesn't exist, copy it from the bundle into the documents directory. You can also use the same approach with a Core Data database, but unless you're familiar with Core Data the learning curve to learning it probably isn't worth it for something as simple as a flashcard app.

Comment: How is Core Data overkill? A plist is certainly not the memory-efficient thing to do. Why sift through the entire data if anything changes?

Comment: @Mundi, I meant overkill in terms of the effort. Core Data is hard to wrap your head around. If you're already climbed the learning curve and are proficient with it then use it by all means, but for a flashcard app you've got a flat, a static database. You don't need SQL queries, indexed searches, joins, KVO updates, or any of that, so Core Data's power does not really come into play.

Comment: True, but Core Data can be also dead simple. Most likely he has to record something about the viewed flash cards, so it is not static. We also should not make any assumptions about the data load.